# Adding new element with JavaScript push method works, but then all elements have the value of the last added element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the push method to add new values to an existing array (st[]). Adding a new value works, but then all values in the array get the value of the last added element.

```
if(!window.WordCatcher){
    WordCatcher = {};
}

WordCatcher.selector = {};

WordCatcher.selector.getSelected = function(){
    var t = '';
        if(window.getSelection) {t = window.getSelection();}
        else if(document.getSelection) {t = document.getSelection();}
        else if(document.selection) {t = document.selection.createRange().text;}
    return t;
}


st = new Array();

WordCatcher.selector.dblclick = function() {
    st.push(WordCatcher.selector.getSelected());
    console.log(st);
}
```

Call the function in jQuery with:

```
$(document).bind("dblclick", WordCatcher.selector.dblclick);
```

Example: If I double click first "Die", second "Smart", third "TV", I will get the following log in firebug:

```
[Die { constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}] [Smart {constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}, Smart {constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}] [TV { constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}, TV {constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}, TV {constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}]
```

Maybe somebody has an idea what I am doing work.

Best regards, 
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your pushing a reference to "t".

everytime its changed - all your array elements are changing , because they are all referencing to the same parameter => "t".

the problem is probably in your function: WordCatcher.selector.getSelected

try to change it to return something else , and check again.

Comment: I just added console.log(t) to the getSelected() and could see that the return value for t seems to be right: Die { constructor=Selection, focusNode=textNode, anchorNode=textNode, mehr...} [Die { constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}] Smart { constructor=Selection, focusNode=textNode, anchorNode=textNode, mehr...} [Smart { constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}, Smart { constructor=Selection,  focusNode=textNode,  anchorNode=textNode,  mehr...}]

Comment: i have no idea what "getSelection" is returning. 
and the console.log is messy.

Comment: change "getSelection" to a function that returns a simple string.
or try changint return t; to something like return t.text();

Comment: Great. Now it works. I added t = t.toString(); in if(window.getSelection) {... 
Thanks for the help, IdanHen

Answer (score 0):

Internal window's selection object is a sort of singleton, that is every getSelection() call returns the same reference to the same object. Thus, you have to manually grab all the data you need, or clone the object, but do not store the immediate result.